# How to get the index value of table?

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

I tried to get the index value of a table using the following methods

```
 if(tbl.getParent() instanceof Body )
{
  Body body = (Body) tbl.getParent();
  int tIndex = body.getContent().indexOf(tbl); 
  body.getContent().remove(tbl); 
}
```

And another method is using contentAccessor

```
 if(tbl.getParent() instanceof ContentAccessor )
{
  ContentAccessor ca = (ContentAccessor) tbl.getParent();
  int tIndex = ca.getContent().indexOf(tbl);
  ca.getContent().remove(tbl); 
}
```

but instead of getting the actual index value I'm getting -1 as the tIndex. Also it is not deleting the tbl(ca.getContent().remove(tbl);) from it's parent.

Is there any other way to get the index value of Tbl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ContentAccessor ca = (ContentAccessor) tbl.getParent();
    int tIndex = getIndex(ca.getContent(), tbl);
    if(tIndex != 98761){
     //do whatever you want to
    }

    private static int getIndex(List<Object> theList, Object bm) 
    {
      for (Object ox : theList) 
      {
        if (XmlUtils.unwrap(ox).equals(bm)) 
        {
            int o = theList.indexOf(ox);
            return o;

        }
      }
    return 98761;

   }
```

In my case tIndex would not touch that much num(98761). If you feel unsafe just increase the return value.